# web.py: how to get POST parameter and GET parameter?

Tags: python, web, web.py

I'm new to `web.py`. I used PHP alot. In PHP, POST parameter and GET parameter is stored in different global variables

For example:

`curl http://127.0.0.1/test?get_param1=1 -d 'post_param1=2'`

In  PHP you can get `$_GET['get_param1']` is 1 and `$_POST['post_param1']` is 2.

But it seems impossible to distinct GET/POST parameters in `web.py`?

I can only use `web.input()` to get GET/POST parameters in a dict-like object, but I cannot tell which of them is from the query string and which is from POST data

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's actually an (undocumented?) `_method` parameter that can be `get`, `post` or `both` (the default) to return variables from the different sources. [See the source for web.input().](https://github.com/webpy/webpy/blob/master/web/webapi.py#L324) So for example:

```
get_input = web.input(_method='get')
post_input = web.input(_method='post')
```

However, I've used web.py a lot, and never needed this. Why do you need to distinguish between input parameters in the query string and the data?

Comment: Just wondering if this worked or helped? If so, please mark the answer as accepted or vote it up, respectively.