# Is there an equivalent of PHP's $_GET or $_POST in web.py

Tags: python, web.py

I'm using a form inside a table, so I can display it as a sudoku grid. web.py's forms seem to dictate the layout of your forms.

Am I doing things the right way ?

Comment: Wild stab but does it have a request object?

Comment: possible duplicate of [web.py: how to get POST parameter and GET parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174738/web-py-how-to-get-post-parameter-and-get-parameter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, although it's a bit difficult to find [the relevant section in the docs](https://github.com/webpy/webpy/blob/73f1119649ffe54ba26ddaf6a612aaf1dab79b7f/docs/input.rst).

GET/POST parameters can be retrieved using [`web.input()`](https://github.com/webpy/webpy/blob/73f1119649ffe54ba26ddaf6a612aaf1dab79b7f/docs/input.rst#get). Each parameter in the query string can be accessed as an attribute of the returned object:

```
class IndexHandler(object):
    def GET(self):
        data = web.input()
        print data.parameter_name
```

Raw POST data can be retrieved using `web.data()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
user_data = web.input()
```

http://webpy.org/cookbook/input

Also checkout [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174738/web-py-how-to-get-post-parameter-and-get-parameter)...